# Solving Cubic Polynomials where coefficients are sum of powers

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Given a set of real numbers $x_1$ to $x_n$ where $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (T - x_i)^3 = 0$
> Solve for $T$ in terms of $x_i$’s and $n$.

---

We could expand the equation to yield:

$n T^3 - 3T^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + 3T \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^3 = 0 $

and solve for $T$ using the cubic polynomial formula with:

- $a = n$
- $b = -3\sum_{i=1}^{n}x$
- $c = 3 \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2}$
- $d = - \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^3$

but this yields a complicated equation that is difficult to simplify.

Is there is a simpler approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Not really. You are basically being asked to solve a general cubic equation, and while [there's a formula for that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), it's not very practical to work with. Numerical solution works best.

Comment: A simpler method for an analytical solution is unlikely to be there in general. What we can say is that will be only one real root, and the mean of $x_i$ is likely to be a good initial value for a numerical search.